# How can i notify lambda result on cloudwatch alarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alarm, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

How can i notify a result of lambda when status OK(normal) and NG both?

I set a alarm on cloudwatch when status NG. It was working.
But when i got OK(normal) status, i couldn't get notify email.
I set up custom metrics by lamda result log when OK(normal) status on cloudwatch alarm.

Is it possible on alarm?
Is there an any simple way?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your requirements are:

- Trigger an AWS Lambda function when a CloudWatch alarm enters the `ALARM` state
- Trigger an AWS Lambda function when a CloudWatch alarm enters the `OK` state

Each AWS CloudWatch alarm can be **configured with multiple Actions**.

Therefore, you can create one Action for `ALARM` and another action for `OK`:

[image: CloudWatch Alarm notification]

The CloudWatch Alarm can send a notification to an Amazon SNS topic. The AWS Lambda function can subscribe to the SNS topic and will be triggered when the alarm sends the notification to SNS.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I think the above settings are couldn't notify state from OK to OK. So, i just want to notify when even normal( OK → OK). Is there any way?

Comment: A notification can only be generated **when an alarm changes state**. There is no facility for sending out continuous notifications of the same status.

Comment: I see. How to monitor a lambda batch is working fine everyday? Is there any other service on aws?

Comment: What do you mean by "monitor a lambda batch is working fine everyday"?

Comment: It means regardless of lambda(OK, ALARM) result, i wanted to know result. 
But it seems impossible only on cloudwatch alarm.

Comment: You could have your application post a Custom Metric to CloudWatch whenever it runs. You could then create a CloudWatch Alarm that triggers if the SUM of the metric is zero (or _INSUFFICIENT_DATA_) over the past _x_ hours. This way, it will tell you if nothing was processed.

Comment: At first, i did as you said the above. As i expected not working because there is no change state. You said too(A notification can only be generated when an alarm changes state.). So i will try send email from lambda by SES. Thank you for discussions. You saved my time :)